# Using an Alias for your photography

Tags: amateur, portfolio

When I owned a blog/magazine, I came up with an alias which was fitting for the author/editor of such a website, and used it for online and forum activities.

As I look at getting into photography, I'm drawn towards using the same alias/username. But, as this is quite a topical alias, it doesn't quite fit all of my photographic subjects.

This makes me look at developping other aliases for photographic subjects that are off-topic so to speak. But this leads me to be too specific.

The obvious thing to do would be:

`RealNamePhotography` & `RealNameAdultPhotography`

But, the truth is, my name isn't all that unique, and as a result I hate using it online, espacially when labeling it specifically `Adult`.

So how could you go about setting up aliases, without being too specific, yet not too broad?

Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should a photographer use a pseudonym when doing two types of photography that might conflict with each other?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/98609/should-a-photographer-use-a-pseudonym-when-doing-two-types-of-photography-that-m)

Comment: Related: [Communicating with all potential clients as a multi niche photographer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/103330/15871) and [Photographers : One or Many Social Personalities](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/106044/15871)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the deal with branding and shooting adult or nsfw subjects...

If shooting bodyscapes is something you like to do on occasion, but you don't make money from it, then don't brand yourself as this type of shooter - keep it to yourself. If you just *have* to showcase some work, do it completely separate from your money making brand.

If you will make money from it, like the many boudoir shooters out there, then create a brand specifically for that. Again, do not mix this with your safe for work money making brand.

If your plan is to run a studio of multiple photographers, then you need a business brand. If it is just you, then devote your name to the bread-and-butter brand (usually the SFW one, at least for most people). Personally, I'd come up with a business name for the adult stuff so that you have YOU as a brand for weddings, sports, family, portraits, etc and a business brand for boudoir, modeling, etc.

This is because the target markets, generally, only overlap in one direction. For example, you may get a client looking for boudoir photos as a wedding present, who may then like your portrait work and want to hire you on for family photos down the road.

However, when Mrs. Suburbia is shopping for family shooters, she doesn't want to stumble upon your adult themed work. If you think there is a cross sale opportunity here, it's something that you pitch in person.

Think of it this way: your online presence is like a version of you that's sitting down at a speed date. If a model sits down across from you looking for modeling photos, it doesn't hurt to lead with some adult themed photos. But if you whip that out to your average client, you'll lose them.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of when web-publishing your work: Some jurisdictions (eg Germany) make a legal notice (with contact information) mandatory for any "business-like" online publication, even if it is not run commercially. However, in many cases there is the possibility of using an official(!!) artists' pseudonym.

Comment: Thanks. Any further details on that anywhere that I can check out? I'm UK based so don't think it's relevant, but worth a look.

Comment: For Germany, the term is "Impressumspflicht". The rules when it applies or does not apply are complicated and best left to legal professionals.